# Convert a string to keys of a given dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

Is there a way to transform a string into the keys of a given dictionary in python?

Here's an example. I have a dictionary and a string

```
dict = {0:'this', 1:'is', 2:'a', 3:'sentence', 4:'another'}
sentence = 'this is a sentence. this is another'
```

And I would like to use the dictionary to convert this string into something like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

Is there a simpler way than a nested loop through the words of the sentence and the items of the dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to reverse the key/values of the dictionary

Comment: the *full-stop* makes it require `regex`. and that is not a good thing.

Comment: `dict` is bad name for variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to reverse your dictionary and then use `re.findall` to search for each word in the string:

```
import re
d = {0:'this', 1:'is', 2:'a', 3:'sentence', 4:'another'}
new_dict = {b:a for a, b in d.items()}
sentence = 'this is a sentence. this is another'
final_words = [new_dict[i] for i in re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', sentence)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

Also, `dict` is a builtin function and when used to store a variable, will have its original functionality overwritten. Thus, it is best to not use the names of the builtin functions to avoid shadowing.

Comment: You could also try splitting on word boundaries

Comment: watch for shadowing

Answer (score 1):

Another *regex* solution (via `re.split()` function):

```
import re

d = {0:'this', 1:'is', 2:'a', 3:'sentence', 4:'another'}
sentence = 'this is a sentence. this is another'
flipped = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}
result = [flipped.get(w) for w in re.split(r'\W+', sentence)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

---

- `\W+` - match one or more of whitespace characters

Comment: I would do `flipped.get(w, w)` but +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

First, do not hide `dict` with new variable name.

```
from re import findall

d = {0:'this', 1:'is', 2:'a', 3:'sentence', 4:'another'}
new_d = {v: k for k, v in d.iteritems()} # or .items() in Python 3.X
sentence = 'this is a sentence. this is another'

print(map(lambda x: new_d[x], findall(r'\w+', sentence))) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one-liner style suggestion in Python3 using list comprehension. Moreover the code readability seems widely acceptable.
Note that `dict` being the name of a built-in class in Python, you must not use it as a variable name. In following code, I replaced your `dict` with `d`:

```
import re

d = {0:'this', 1:'is', 2:'a', 3:'sentence', 4:'another'}
sentence = 'this is a sentence. this is another'

result = [a for word in re.findall('\w+', sentence) for a,b in d.items() if word == b])
print(result)
```